# "You don't have an extension for debugging 'JSON with Comments'" warning when debugging VS Code theme

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-debugging, vscode-debugger

I generated the files necessary for creating a color theme in VS Code. I did this with the [generator-code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-code) node package.

[My file structure is as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHL8k.png)

When I run VS Code's debugger, I get [this warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW47e.png) that prevents the debugger from running.

Here are the contents of my launch.json file for reference:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
      {
          "name": "Extension",
          "type": "extensionHost",
          "request": "launch",
          "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
          "args": [
              "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
          ],
          "outFiles": [
              "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
          ],
      }
  ]
}
```

In case you're wondering what I'm expecting to happen when I run the debugger, [here's the moment](https://youtu.be/pGzssFNtWXw?t=369) in the tutorial I was following where I ran into this problem.

**Edit:** Well, I evaded the problem somehow by deleting the files and starting over. I'm not sure what was causing the problem before.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

This popup only appears for me when trying to launch the debugger while having the launch.json or tasks.json file open. Switching to one of my test files and launching the debugger fixes it

Comment: tasks.json is another very typical one to have open that would cause this. I tried to add it to your answer, but the suggested edit queue was full.

Comment: Thanks @Gerry . I added that to the answer

Answer (score 2):

Try Adding Configurations (Menu-->Run-->Add Configuration-->your browser)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the folder you have the extension code in is the folder you open in VSCode.  It has to  be the root project folder in VSCode for the extension to be run.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when my launch.json was not according to the `version` + `configurations` scheme, I copy pasted the content of `configurations` to the file instead of putting it in the array.

```json
{
    "name": "Extension",
    "type": "extensionHost",
    "request": "launch",
    "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
    "args": [
        "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
    ],
    "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/out/**/*.js"
    ],
}
```