# "You don't have an extension for debugging 'JSON with comments' " Error when trying to debug VSCode theme

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I created and published a VSCode colour theme, using the debug feature to see what it would look like. Now, when I try to debug it, it gives me a *"You don't have an extension for debugging 'JSON with comments'* error.
I didn't change anything in the launch JSON file in between it working and now.

**launch.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Extension",
      "type": "extensionHost",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**file structure**
[image: screenshot of the file structure]

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68424936/you-dont-have-an-extension-for-debugging-json-with-comments-warning-when-de), however, the user solved the problem by just deleting and restarting, which isn't ideal for me (as I have published it already and want to maintain it).

The accepted answer also suggests closing launch.json or tasks.json, however, the error still persists, even after restarting VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `launch.json` I use for theme extensions

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": ["--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceRoot}" ],
            "stopOnEntry": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred because I  had opened the parent folder of the extension rather than the folder of the extension itself.